# What is the reverse image of $f:[0,6\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f = sinx$?

Tags: analysis, functions

What is the reverse image of $f:[0,6\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \sin x$?
Specifically, I need to find the reverse image of an interval $[a,b]$. I know that this will be a group, as $\sin x$ isn't one to one. Looking at the $\sin x$ graph I can almost see it but I"m not sure I can describe it formally. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By reverse image, do you mean preimage?

Comment: I guess, I mean that the reverse "function" isn't a function.

Comment: There is an equivalence class, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: The reverse image is a group ?

Comment: For an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The word "group" is unfortunately taken in mathematics; you mean to say that the preimage will be disconnected.

Comment: If $a > -1$ or $b < 1$ then the preimage will be a union of several disjoint intervals; is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm fairly certain he's asking for an inverse function